# Encrypt the video downlink stream from the DJI Matrice 100

Tags: encryption, dji-sdk

I'm trying to encrypt the video downlink from the DJI M100 drone. 
my problem is that I don't understand the structure - what is the frame path ? there is the N1, lightbridge2, gimbal camera ... 
it will be grate to get some info on it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample.
It shows you how to get raw video frames from the drone and decode it using FFMPEG.

https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample

Here is the link to full tutorial

http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/sample-code/index.html